# create select option from string using explode in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, phpmyadmin

I have an issue with creating select options from a string.

I want to explode the string into an array split on the comma separator, and then create options from that array.

I have this string:

> Triple Berry,Orange,Blueberry

I use this code for creation:

```
$query = "select c_flavour from product_detail WHERE p_id='".$p_id."' ";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
   $f = explode(',', $row['c_flavour']);
   for ($x = 0; $x < $f; $x++) {    
    echo '<option value="'.$f[$x].'">'.$f[$x].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Do you know about `foreach`? It's the easier way to loop through an array.

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop the infinite loop, you're missing the [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) of array elements.

I also added the `<select>` tag in case you were missing that element.

```
<?php

$row['c_flavour'] = "Triple Berry,Orange,Blueberry";

$f = explode(',', $row['c_flavour']);

echo "<select>".PHP_EOL;

// this is where you need to use count()
for ($x = 0; $x < count($f); $x++) {    
  echo '<option value="'.$f[$x].'">'.$f[$x].'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
}

echo "</select>".PHP_EOL;
```

I added [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) just for readability.

which results in this output

```html
<select>
<option value="Triple Berry">Triple Berry</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Blueberry">Blueberry</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Trusharnarodia if you accept my answer, then it will up your rep by +2